# How to select multiple files (image,video file, capture) and upload later in Apache Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, phonegap

I have an cordova application for user registration with multiple pages.

In some pages, you need to select an image from the gallery, and on the other page, you need to select a video file or capture a video from the camera.

At the end of the registration form is a submit button. How would I go about capturing those said images, files, and video with data text (first name, last nam etc), at the end of the page? I am assuming the URI will need to be saved first.

I did this by saving them to the localStorage and retrieve them at the end of the page.

By the way I am using:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-simulate

For the simulation as its fast to debug and test. One thing I noticed though is when I use the `camera.getPicture` using `FILE_URI` sourceType.

I get a blob:http://localhost:8000/57187db8-0047-47ae-a8da-520d625d99ca. The documentation (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/)  say, for browsers you get a base64 encode. But to me it doesnt look like a base64 image, but a URI.

Anyways I been trying to figure this out for days and searching the internet. Thanks!

Comment: you have to use `DATA_URL` as mentioned in the document https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#cameradestinationtype--enum

Comment: @ajaiJothi as document says its not advisable to use. Im looking for overview of how its going to work and the logic that entails my needs. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Once you have the URI, you need to pull the contents with AJAX on whatever framework you're using. I use AngularJS and did it with `$http.get(file_uri, {'responseType':'blob'}).then(successMethod, failMethod);`. That returned a blob which I then used to upload to a server.